# How to prevent new addition data replacing the previous data in Firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, mobile-application

**EDIT:**
I’m trying to add additional data into Cloud Firestore under the same UID. However, the new data deletes the old data and rewrites on it.  Because as for the result later, I am desired to show every data of the same UID on my UI.

I have also checked on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55767625/firestore-adding-multiple-data-under-the-same-uid) but it was in javascript and I am not sure on how to apply it on my code. Thank you.

this is my program code.

```
 @IBAction func newBookTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid,
                      let data = bookData() else {
                          return
                      }
                db.collection("bookData").document(uid).setData(data)
            }
            
        
            func bookData() -> [String: Any]? {
                guard let title = bookTitleTextField.text,
                      let author = bookAuthorTextField.text,
                      let summary = bookSummaryTextField.text else {
                          return nil
                      }
                let data: [String: Any] = [
                    "bookTitle": title,
                    "bookAuthor": author,
                    "bookSummary": summary
                ]
                
                self.transitionToMenu()
                
                return data
    }
```

Comment: You are using `uid` as your document ID, which will be constant as long as you are logged in as the same user.

Comment: I see, so I should change it into what?

Comment: I don't know  swift but I think you should use the push() method in order to get a unique key for every entry

Comment: It may be more appropriate to create a "books" collection under your uid document and then create a document for each book in that collection.

Comment: @Paulw11 is it like `db.collection("users").document("uid").collection("bookData")`?

Comment: Yes, but you would have `uid` not `"uid"`

Comment: @Paulw11 it didnt show up in the firebase

Comment: Hi, Please explain what didn't show up? Edit the question and add what you have tried and also add if you are receiving any error.